# How to make someone prone without a shove / strength check?

Tags: dnd-5e, prone

I want to trip an enemy so he falls prone because our DM made a house rule about prone.

In 5e, trip attack is a specific maneuver that only a Battle Master Fighter (or someone with the Martial Adept feat) can learn. There is also the option to shove someone with a Strength(Athletics) vs. Strength(Athletics) or Dexterity(Acrobatics) check.

Assume a non-fighter without the Martial Adept feat and Strength: 8.

What ways are there to make someone prone with a reasonable success rate? Anything a player can control is fine. Things like magic items that are handed out by the DM are not what I am looking for.

A good answer explains the best ways and quickly discusses the pro and cons of each.

Comment: If you're an untrained weakling, what makes you think there's ANY method that will "with reasonable success" knock prone another person? (Especially one who is likely stronger, better trained, and better equipped than you are?)

Comment: Because magic. If there is no way, write an answer explaining that; then if no one contradicts you, you get the points...

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to knock prone and/or any information on your type of character? If you're looking for spells or magic items that can knock prone it's a different kind of question. (Especially because you word it as "want to trip")

Comment: Our DM has a house rule for prone that makes it stronger. I want to find out the ways to make prone, and then build a character to take advantage of the one I like best. So anything that a player can control goes (no magic items, since they are handed out by the DM).

Comment: You should probably edit that information into the question.

Comment: Harsh language sometimes works

Comment: Voting to close - this appears to be looking for a list of every spell or ability that can render an opponent prone.

Comment: you could always try seducing them...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get creative with improvising during combat.

Fifth edition codifies a list of actions you can take in combat, but these are explicitly non-exhaustive:

> The only limits to the actions you can attempt are your imagination and your character's ability scores. [...] When you describe an action not detailed elsewhere in the rules, the DM tells you whether that action is possible and what kind of roll you need to make, if any, to determine success or failure. (*PHB*, p. 193)

To handle everything else that a character can do, 5e provides DMs with rules for Contests (*DMG*, p. 238), to be used by the DM as needed to resolve such declarations. The exact two Attribute Checks to make as an opposed roll, and the stakes to be won or lost, are entirely under the DM's adjudication, but based on what you improvise.

So get creative. This edition busts combat options wide open, but it's up to each player to take advantage of that.

### But doesn't this step on the Battle Master's toes?

Not at all. The Battle Master's **Trip** maneuver is strictly superior to *just* tripping an opponent as it also does weapon damage. It's also much more likely to work than an opposed Attribute Check, as it's an attack roll vs. AC using a Fighter's attack bonuses.

Comment: A perfect answer. Also loved the explanation as to why it does not step on someone's toes.

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it explicitly ignores the paragraph in the question stating that the asker is only interested in options that are entirely dependent on player agency: "What ways are there to make someone prone with a reasonable success rate? Anything a player can control is fine. Things like magic items that are handed out by the DM are not what I am looking for." Because this answer's proposal requires DM cooperation in order to be viable, it clearly does not fit the question as it was asked.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac That's just 5e for you. None of it, including even PC builds, are exclusively under player control.

Answer (score 2):

Paladin Thunderous Smite leaps to mind:

> The first time you hit with a melee weapon attack
>   during this spell’s duration, your weapon rings with
>   thunder that is audible within 300 feet o f you, and the
>   attack deals an extra 2d6 thunder damage to the target.
>   Additionally, if the target is a creature, it must succeed
>   on a Strength saving throw or be pushed 10 feet away
>   from you **and knocked prone**.

Answer (score 2):

**Clerics**, **Paladins**, and **Warlocks** (those who chose the Fiend patron) all have access to the 1st-level spell *Command*. Additionally, you could get access to the spell from any other class using the Magic Initiate feat though you would only be able to cast it once per day.

The *Command* spell has many example commands, but the one we are most interested in for the purposes of this answer is **Grovel**. Commanding a creature who fails its Wisdom save to grovel causes it to immediately go prone during it's next turn and forbids the target from doing anything else until the following turn, meaning it is forced to remain prone for an entire round. Note that in order for *Command* to work, the creature must be able to understand (but not necessarily speak) your language.